# problema con UITableView y pasando de un view controller a otro

Tags: xcode, swift3, uitableview

Hola amigos el problema es el siguiente estoy intentando un taleView con que contenga divisores y en esas divisiones diferentes cosas y cuando se toca una de ella mandaria a otra vista es decir un segue el problema es que cuando se tocan siempre mandan a la misma vista es decir el mismo segue , trate de diferentes forma pero siempre doy en lo mismo pasan a una sola vista las celdas

```
    import UIKit
    class ViewControllerGeometry: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource {
        var tableArray : [Problems] = []
        var tableArrayGeometryProblem : [Problemp] = []

         var segueIdentifiers = ["prueba" , "B", "C"]



        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            let geometryproblem = Problems (name : "a")
            tableArray.append(geometryproblem)


            let perimeterProblem = Problemp(nameGeometryProblem: "c")
            tableArrayGeometryProblem.append(perimeterProblem)

            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        }
        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }


        func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return 4
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {



            switch section{
            case 0:
                return tableArray.count

            case 1 :

                return tableArrayGeometryProblem.count



            default:
                return 0
            }


        }




        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellGeometryproblem")! as  UITableViewCell


            let geometryproblem = tableArray [indexPath.row]

            let perimeterProblemCalculation = tableArrayGeometryProblem [indexPath.row]
            switch indexPath.section {

            case 0:

                cell.textLabel?.text = geometryproblem.name
            case 1 :
                cell.textLabel?.text = perimeterProblemCalculation.nameGeometryProblem


            default:
                return cell
            }




            return cell
        }
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: segueIdentifiers[indexPath.row], sender: self)
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
            var title = ""


            switch section {
            case 0:
                title = "Area calculation "
            case 1 :

                title = "Pe

rimeter calculation "

        case 2 :

            title = "Sen theorem "

        case 3 :

            title = "Inside angles of the triangle "



        default:
            break
        }
        return title
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que entiendo, pulses donde pulses siempre te vas al mismo controlador, al que esta apuntando el segue de "prueba". Si es así, creo que tienes un poco de lío con sections y rows.

Tienes definido 2 arrays, tableArray y tableArrayGeometryProblem y cada array solo tiene 1 elemento.
En la tabla defines 4 secciones (func numberOfSections) y para saber cuantas celdas hay en cada sección devuelves el numero de elementos de los arrays, pero solo para las 2 primeras secciones.
El problema de que siempre vaya al mismo controlador pulses donde pulses viene dado en el método func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)

Le estas indicando que se vaya al segue que esta en la posición indexPath.row de tu array de segues, ya que en cualquier seccion solo tienes una fila, así que pulses donde pulses, indexPath.row = 0 siempre. El valor de segueIdentifiers[0] = "prueba"

Si lo que quieres hacer es que según pulses en en la primera celda de la primera sección o en la primera celda de la segunda sección te vayas a "prueba, "B" o "C" tienes que comprobar la sección, no la row. Así pues debes poner:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: segueIdentifiers[indexPath.section], sender: self)
```

Y tienes que asegurar que cuando tengas 4 secciones con valores, al pinchar sobre la ultima va a cascar porque no existe segueIdentifiers[3].
En este caso, tampoco se ira por el segue "C"